# in Angular 8.x is there a way to catch progress event of http requests using .toPromise() instead of .subscribe()?

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

Is there a way to catch the progress of the uploading/downloading of http request after .toPromise()ing the request?
The Documentation of Angular shows how to use `reportProgress: boolean = true` and then subscribe to http.request invocation.
i.e.:

```
httpClient.post(url, body, {reportProgress: true})
.pipe(map(event=> {
    //do something with the progress event
    }))
.subscribe(...);
```

What I'm trying to figure out: is it possible to use toPromise() instead of .subscribe() and get progress events while file is being uploaded/downloaded?
i.e. something like this:

```
return httpClient.post(url, body, {reportProgress: true})
.pipe(map(event=> {
    //do something with the progress event
    }))
.toPromise();
```

Comment: Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318977/checking-progress-during-promise I hope this might help!

Comment: @BhavyaShah yes it does. thanks